# Not find Current selected live wallpaper Drawable

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to find Currently selected Live Wallpaper `drawable` , but this code every time returns me Default Live wallpaper `Drawable`, While my custom live wallpaper is set to my device.

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance( this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable1 = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable1);
```

But Docs says it will return Currently selected live wallpaper, whats wrong with it,Is there any requirement to any permission in `manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

Every live wallpaper will be found as a package in the device. So each live wallpaper package contains a drawable image, which we can get easily.

The method `getWallpaperInfo()` is used to get the information about the live wallpapers.

So `getWallpaperInfo().loadThumbnail(PackageManager pm)` method will do the trick for you.

The following code is used to get the drawable image of the live wallpaper:

```
    //Reference to the package manager instance
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    /*
     * Wallpaper info is not equal to null, that is if the live wallpaper
     * is set, then get the drawable image from the package for the 
     * live wallpaper
     */
    if (wallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo() != null) {
         wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager
                .getWallpaperInfo().loadThumbnail(pm);
    } 

    /*
     * Else, if static wallpapers are set, then directly get the 
     * wallpaper image
     */
    else {
         wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    }
```

Comment: This does not actually work.  For live wallpapers, it can (and often does) simply return a generic thumbnail representing any image.  Tested with the google "Wallpapers" app.

Comment: loadThumbnail might return null though getWallpaperInfo() isn't null. So whoever gonna use this code, make sure to check the returned drawable against null before using it to avoid NullPointerException.